# Is there any way to make this code shorter, and more efficient?

Tags: javascript, html

I was learning javascript, and trying different projects/coding challenges. After writing this code I realised that it is 43 lines (this is for a basic image slider), and it could not be the most efficient method for doing this. Is there any way to shorten my code, or make it more efficient?
This script says when you press right, it goes to the next image, and when you press left, it goes to the previous image

```js
// Try edit message
const data = [
  {
    image:"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg",
  },
  {
    image:"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg",
  },
]

let img = document.querySelector("img")
let left = document.querySelector('#left')
let right = document.querySelector('#right')
let origin = 0
img.src = data[origin].image

function incr(number){
  if (number == 'left') {
    if (origin - 1 >= 0){
      origin += -1
    }else{
      origin = data.length - 1
    }
  }else if (number == 'right'){
    if (origin + 1 <= data.length - 1){
      origin += 1
    }else{
      origin = 0
    }
    }
  return origin;
  }

function moveleft(){
  let value = incr('left')
  img.src = data[value].image
}

function moveright(){
  let value = incr('right')
  img.src = data[value].image
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" width = 1280px height = 720px>
  <button onclick = "moveleft()" id = 'left'>left</button>
  <button onclick = "moveright()" id = 'right'>right</button>
</div>
```

All help apreciated, thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about improving working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function incr(offset) {
  // either +1 or +(-1)
  const incremented = origin + offset;
  // Take the smallest value out of the 2, effectively constrains to <= len - 1
  const constrainedUpper = Math.min(data.length - 1, incremented); 
  // Take the largest value out of the 2, effectively constrains to >= 0
  const constrainedLower = Math.max(0, constrainedUpper);
  origin = constrainedLower;
}

function moveleft(){
  incr(-1)
  img.src = data[origin].image;
}

function moveright(){
  incr(1)
  img.src = data[origin].image
}
```

Removing the `'left'` and `'right'` since they are really just indicators for how much you want to move. Then, use the math functions to constrain the result to `0` and `data.length - 1`.

Comment: good answer.  why not combine the moveleft moveright functions while you're at it?

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible, fixing variable names + casing etc, but just wanted to address the question at hand without too much change.

Comment: I split it out line by line.

Comment: A quick problem with this is that it does not take the pattern back to the beginning once completed

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it easily with the ternary operator